# What were the previous Binance coin burns as stated in the white paper before 2018 April?

Tags: binance, binance-coin

What happened to the price prior to the Binance coin burn as stated in the white paper? How high did the coin go in terms of BTC prior to the burn and after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on their website. They plan to burn 100 million coins every quarter by burning 20% of their profits in BNB. Currently have have burned 2 million so far.

Q1: https://support.binance.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002205552-Binance-1st-Quarter-BNB-Burn-Event

Q2: https://support.binance.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012892-Binance-Coin-Burn-in-2018-Winter